# Allocating memory not working

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm trying to allocate some memory as unsigned char* however when I do the pointer doesn't seem to have been initialized!

```
    unsigned char* split = (unsigned char*) malloc ((sizeof(unsigned char)*sizeof(unsigned int)));
    memset(&split,0,sizeof(int));
    if(split==NULL) {
       std::cout<<"Unable to allocate memory!\n";
       system("pause");
       return 1;
    }
```

However every single time I run I get the error message. It seems to happen no matter what data type I use as well!

Comment: Have you seen `union` yet?

Comment: you are passing address of a pointer to memset. Try passing the pointer

Comment: You'd be better off testing `split == NULL` before messing around with it, whether correct or incorrectly as you are doing here. If you use `calloc()` you can get rid of the `memset()` altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `memset` call doesn't write to the buffer you've just allocated, the one pointed to by `split`. It writes to the area of memory where `split` variable itself stored - as pointed to by `&split`. Whereupon `split` becomes `NULL`.

Comment: Well now I feel really stupid. Removing the & fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `memset()`, you are zeroing the memory occupied by the `split` variable itself, not the memory that `split` points to (the memory that `malloc()` allocated). You need to remove the `&` operator:

```
unsigned char* split = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(int));
if(split==NULL) {
   std::cout<<"Unable to allocate memory!\n";
   system("pause");
   return 1;
}
memset(split,0,sizeof(int));
```